# How to disable model view check box in .net mvc?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to disable model view check box in .net mvc?

I tried with the syntax :  new { disabled = "disabled" }  but doesn't work.

```
<div class="col-sm-7 checkbox-inline text-left">
                        <label style="margin-right:15px"></label>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Email, new { disabled = "disabled" } )  <label class="hthin" asp-for="Email" style="margin-right:30px"></label>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Pager, new { disabled = "disabled" })  <label class="hthin" asp-for="Pager" style="margin-right:30px"></label>
                        @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.Landline, new { disabled = "disabled" })  <label class="hthin" asp-for="Landline" style="margin-right:30px"></label>
</div>
```

Comment: Do not accept incorrect answers - it just misleads other users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Html.CheckBoxFor() - model object property should be boolean.

Thanks Stephen Muecke. I updated my answer. @ symbol is used for reserved keywords. For example @class.

Thanks GregH. You catch it perfect.

Comment: i tried the same syntax.. with @disabled= "disabled " but doesnt help much

Comment: set empty `@disabled = ""`

Comment: @goofyui can you post what the rendered html looks like when using the posted answer here? I've just put together a use case testing this and it's working for me

Comment: Also, I'm assuming that `model.Email`, `model.Pager`, `model.Landline` are all booleans. You should be getting an error if they aren't so...

Comment: @GregH, Yes that is correct. All those 3 are set as bool

Comment: They are bit data type in the back end. bool in the model

Comment: @GregH , Do you think .. having Boolean data type is what causing the issue. If that's case, if i changed to Int .. will that resolve the issue.

Comment: no. boolean is fine. Please edit your post and include what the rendered html looks like. As a side note, disabling inputs isn't generally an extremely safe way to prevent the data from being changed since someone can manually edit the html and remove the disabled attribute then post that data if it is submitted to the server via ajax event or form submission

Comment: @GregH, Thank you for your help..there was a Javascript validation file which was doing additional validation. Issue was on my end. Now it is resolved . Thank you. I was concerned about Bool data type

Comment: You do not need the `@` in `@disabled` - that is only required for reserved keywords. This answer has nothing to do with OP's issue!